# child.kill() does not kill the running process

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I have this block of code:

```
const childProcess = require("child_process");

let child;

before(function(done) {
 // 'npm start' starts an express server.
 child = childProcess.exec(["npm start"]);
 done();
});

// My tests run here

after(function() {
  child.kill();
});
```

The `node.exe` process *never stops running*. I can see it running when if I log running processes.

This is what happens in the server file when the `npm start` command runs :

```
const app   = express();
app.listen(process.env.PORT || app.get("port"), function() {
console.log("HTTP listening on *:" + app.get("port"));
});
```

I m using mocha.js to run my tests

Comment: It would be hard to say without knowing what's in the program that is started by `npm start`. It could be possible that something in there is block the interrupt signal. You could try passing `'SIGTERM'` to `kill()`. Also, what are you using to run your tests. Also, `exec` takes a callback that is run when the child process terminates. You could try adding a callback and that might help give you some clues as to what's happening.  `stdout` and `stderr` are passed to the callback. Lastly, try using `spawn` instead of `exec` and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: made any progress?

Comment: No , not at all , i posted the code of the server file . I tried using spawn instead of exec but it didn't work neither 'SIGTERM'